# Porque a tag <p> não herda a cor de seu pai?

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte código bem simples

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    
    p#father {
        color: red;
    }

    p#child {
        color: inherit;
    }
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
<p id="father">
    pai
    <p id="child">
        filho
        <p id="child2">
            filho 2
        </p>
    </p>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

O que acontece é que era para a tag com `id#child` herdar o `color: red` do parágrafo `id#father`. E não acontece, Por que ?

Answer (score 6):

Sua sintaxe está incorreta, você não pode ter um parágrafo `<p>`dentro de outro parágrafo.

Se você alterar os filhos para um elemento permitido (dentro da tag `<p>`) como por exemplo um `<span>` Você verá que os filhos herdarão automaticamente a cor do pai.

E caso você deseje trocar a cor de algum filho basta aplicar o css somente no filho desejado. Veja:

```css
#father {
  color: red;
}

#child2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p id="father" style="color:red">
    pai
    <span id="child">
        filho
        <span id="child2">
            filho 2
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Vim postar a resposta e vc já tinha colocar exatamente o que eu iria colocar +1

Comment: Opa, valeu colega

Answer (score 6):

O problema é que o Browser corrige seu código. Assim como o Vinicius falou, não é adequado colocar um `<p>` dentro de outro. Quando vc faz isso o motor de renderização do browser faz isso com seu código

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo assim, com o browser fechando automaticamente seus `<p>` quando vc coloca `inherit` na verdade ele herda a cor do `body` e não do pai, pois ele não tem pai!

**OBS:** Esse comportamento pode mudar de browser para browser.

O **FireFox** tb fecha os `<p>` automaticamente e não renderiza um `<p>` dentro de outro...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS2:** No HTML5 a tag `<p>` não precisa de uma tag de fechamento `</p>`, apesar disso recomendo que use...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

Comment: Obrigado, hugocsl não sabia disso dos browser. E cara tu ta em todo canto do stackoverflow ;)

Comment: @LeandroNascimento hahaha de acordo com a minha noiva "eu sou viciado nesse joguinho" rss. Mas compartilhar o conhecimento é muito bom, valeu a força!

Comment:  é isso ai, conhecimento é a chave para o futuro. O mundo se move e temos que se mover junto com ele hehehe.